# PostgreSQL REST API Pagination

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I'm following [Pagination Done the Right Way](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way), which orders by `date` for `news`.

I want to order by `created_at` (a `timestamp`) for `posts` (like Facebook posts).

According to [PostgreSQL Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html), `timestamp` has a resolution of 1 microsecond.

The API's clients, however, only need (to display) whole seconds.

So, should I just round `created_at` to whole seconds (with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)`) by default when inserting new posts?

That way, to get the next page, the client can simply send back to the REST API server the `created_at` `timestamp` (in whole seconds) of the last post it received.

Otherwise, the client would have to know the exact `created_at` `timestamp` (down to the microseconds) of the last post it received.

Is there any reason to store the exact microseconds in the database (especially if they're never sent to the clients)? Isn't a whole second enough precision for something like Facebook (or Instagram) posts?